# function static variable destructor and thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, c++11

I have the a simple program.

```
int main() 
{
    std::atomic<bool> b = true;
    ConcurrentQueue<std::string> queue;

    std::thread thread( [&]{
        while ( b ) {
            auto str = queue.wait_and_pop();
            std::cout << *str;
        }
    });

    b = false;
    queue.push( "end" );
    thread.join();
}
```

`ConcurrentQueue<T>` is my own implementation of thread safe queue, `wait_and_pop` is a blocking operation that use `std::condition_variable`.

this program successfully prints "end" and exits, no problem here. ( there is a bug that `b` is false when `thread` started which cause it to exit immediately but that is not relevant here )

But if I wrap all these in a class

```
class object {
public:
    object() {
        b = true;

        thread = std::thread( [this]{
            while ( b ) {
                auto str = queue.wait_and_pop();
                std::cout << *str;
            }
        });
    }

    ~object() {
        b = false;
        queue.push( "end" );
        thread.join();
    }

private:
    std::atomic<bool> b;
    std::thread thread;
    ConcurrentQueue<std::string> queue;
};
```

and have a function static variable like

```
object & func() {
  static object o;
  return o;
}
```

and main

```
int main() {
    object & o = func();
}
```

now the program prints "end" then stuck at destructor of `o` at line `thread.join()`.

I have tested this with clang and no problem. This seem to only happen in VC11. Why is that?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code as-is.  One possibility is that you have found a bug in VC11's handling of thread spawning in static initializers, which seems like an edge case that might be buggy.  Another is that you have a bug in ConcurrentQueue, which you don't show.

Comment: When will the static object o get deleted?

Comment: dauphic: it looks correct to me: set the atomic flag, push a record to ensure at least one wakeup after the flag is set, and then wait for the inevitable thread exit.

Comment: Yes. I misread the code and thought the join was occurring in `main` for some reason. It looks fine.

Comment: @AndyRoss I replaced my `ConcurrentQueue` with TBB's `tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue` and the problem still persist.

Comment: @doctorlove - the static object will never be deleted. It will be destroyed after `main` returns.

Comment: About your bug with `b` being false when the thread starts, this is because the value initialization of an atomic object is not an atomic operation and doesn't guarantee any memory order / fences. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic). You can use either [ATOMIC_VAR_INIT](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_VAR_INIT), or create the atomic and then assign a value to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There recently was a thread with the same problem, but I can't find it anymore.

Basically, there's a deadlock in VS's runtime library when you have a static lifetime object that tries to end a thread in its destructor.

Comment: join before the destructor works... seems like a temporary work around until they fix it. Thanks