# Waiting for a std::thread to finish

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I am trying to clean up gracefully on program termination, so I'm calling `join()` on a `std::thread` to wait for it to finish. This simply seems to block the main thread forever, but I don't understand why, because the worker thread is an (almost) empty loop like this:

```
void GameLoop::Run()
{
    while (run)
    {
        //  Do stuff... 
    }   
    std::cout << "Ending thread...\n";
}
```

I'm setting `run` to false before `join`ing, of course. Now, I'm suspecting it's got something to do with it being a member function and being called upon object *destruction*. I'm creating the thread like this: `runThread.reset(new thread(&GameLoop::Run, this));`, where `runThread` is `unique_ptr<std::thread>` and a member of `GameLoop`. The `join()` call comes in the destructor of the `GameLoop` object.

Maybe the loop thread cannot finish if its object is in the process of being destroyed? According to the debugger the loop thread lingers on in the dark depths of `msvcr120d.dll`. If so, how would you handle it?

Beware: new to `std::thread` here!

**Update:** This is my call to join in the destructor:

```
run = false;
if (runThread->joinable())
{
    runThread->join();
}
```

**Update 2:** If I remove the `join()` I get an exception raised by `~thread()`!

Comment: I hope you set run to false/0 somewhere... It is a good idea to define it as volatile.

Comment: Do you ever set `run` to `false`? What joining a thread does is put your calling thread to sleep until the target thread is dead (with its various meanings), which is exactly what you're seeing. It doesn't kill the thread itself.

Comment: Yes of course. The message is being printed and all.

Comment: While updating your question, also mention what `thread::joinable` returns, if the thread isn't joinable you obviously shouldn't join on it. What happens if you remove the join? If the program closes fine (check task manager) it means the thread was successfully cleared by the compiler.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for your destructor?

Comment: @AlexFarber - it's an even better idea to define it as `std::atomic`. `volatile` has no portable semantics, and isn't useful for inter-thread synchronization.

Comment: If you remove the join(), you get an exception because the thread object cannot be destructed until the thread finishes (except if detach has been called on it).

Comment: I have no trouble with what you describe your code does...http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7555dac44353ca50

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I don't see why it's happening here. Must be something to do with destruction, I think, because if I call the join code before the program doesn't freeze.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094422/how-to-check-if-a-stdthread-is-still-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh, apparently there's a bug in the runtime library. Threads are not ended successfully in destructors of static objects according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239749/function-static-variable-destructor-and-thread). My `GameLoop` is a non-static object contained in a static `GameSystem`. I'll check whether this is true and update.

Yep, confirmed. Just my luck to hit a bug on first use!

Comment: Well you'll also want to ensure that `run` functions properly in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've changed it to an atomic<bool>, but I wonder: for such a small variable like a bool, is there a real concern to make it an atomic, if one thread is only writing and another is only reading?

Comment: @KristianD'Amato No, if you're comfortable trusting the compiler when the behavior of multiple threads accessing a non-atomic variable is explicitly undefined behavior in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, when you `join` a thread that doesn't cause the thread to terminate.  It simply blocks until that thread dies of natural (or unnatural) causes.

In order to clean up a multithreaded application gracefully, you need to somehow tell the worker thread that it is time to die, and then wait for the death to happen.  The "wait for death to happen" part is what `join` is for.

Comment: I'm setting run to false. Let me update the question.