# std::thread::join blocks indefinitely out of main

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

`std::thread::join` does not return, even if the thread routine is exited.

Guess, I have a class.

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        this->thr = std::thread(&A::foo, this);
    }
    ~A()
    {
        this->join();
    }
    void join()
    {
        this->cond.notify_all();
        if (this->thr.joinable())
        {
            this->thr.join();
        }
    }

private:
    void foo()
    {
        std::mutex mtx;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        this->cond.wait(lck);
        MessageBox(L"I'm done!");
    }

private:
    std::thread thr;
    std::condition_variable cond;
};
```

My application contains the only instance of `A`. It is a global variable.
If `A::join` is called from the destructor, `std::thread::join` blocks forever.
If I call `A::join` manually (e.g. before exiting `main`), everything is alright.

My `main` looks like this:

```
A a;
int main()
{
    auto timeout = std::chrono::seconds(3);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout);

    // a.join();
}
```

By the way, MessageBox is always executed.

Is that the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239749/function-static-variable-destructor-and-thread)?

Comment: Did [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17239943/2069064) not answer your question?

Comment: @Barry, It doesn't seem to be a great solution. I works, but what if the `main` is not so trivial? There're a lot of different ways of exiting from my application. Thus, I've got to `join` my threads manually every time I need it?

Comment: @MAKAKOKO Sorry I was confused on what was going on.  I retracted the comment.

Comment: Btw put `notify_all()` under mutex, you have race condition there

Comment: The example works fine on vs2015 (with and without `a.join()`, `MessageBox` call was corrected) and there is no race condition with `notify_all()`.

Comment: @knivil Could be this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915233/stdthreadjoin-hangs-if-called-after-main-exits-when-using-vs2012-rc - and maybe that is why it works on 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is the same bug as in the referenced link since your example also hangs on `_Thrd_join`. You could be interrested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915233/stdthreadjoin-hangs-if-called-after-main-exits-when-using-vs2012-rc) which contains a far more detailed analysis.

Comment: That's it! Unfortunately, I can't vote up. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @JohnSmith as person who considers VS to be the best possible IDE such errors in the runtime make me sad:(

Answer (score 1):

from your comment

> "It doesn't seem to be a great solution. I works, but what if the main
>   is not so trivial? There're a lot of different ways of exiting from my
>   application. Thus, I've got to join my threads manually every time I
>   need it?"

how about making A a std::unique_ptr within your main. that way, no matter how your main exits, it'll always destroy A before exiting main() and you won't have this problem.